# LINQ to Xml not equal to operator

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I am using LINQ to XML. I want to use an equivalent of sql's `<>` operator in the `where` clause below....

```
var myBooks = from book in xDoc.Descendants("BOOKOB") 
              where book.Element("AUTHOR").Value
```

Please help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Isn't != working?

Answer (score 3):

As others have said, you can use != perfectly easily - don't forget that even when you're using LINQ, you're writing C#, *not* SQL.

You need to provide a value for it not to be equal to, of course, along with a `select` clause:

```
var myBooks = from book in xDoc.Descendants("BOOKOB") 
              where book.Element("AUTHOR").Value != "Jeff Atwood"
              select book;
```

For simple queries like this, I usually find "dot notation" simpler to read:

```
var myBooks = xDoc.Descendants("BOOKOB")
                  .Where(b => b.Element("AUTHOR").Value != "Jeff Atwood");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use != for not equal and == for equal to.